# std::lock_guard<std::mutex> segfaults on construction?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, mutex

I'm attempting to access a shared std::queue using a std::mutex and a std::lock_guard. The mutex (pending_md_mtx_) is a member variable of another object (whose address is valid). My code seems to be segfault'ing on the construction of the lock_guard.

Any ideas? Should I be using a std::unique_lock (or some other object) instead? Running GCC 4.6 (--std=c++0x) under Ubuntu Linux. I can't post the entire class, but the only accesses to the mutex and queue listed below.

```
template <typename ListenerT>
class Driver
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Driver(Args&&... args) :
        listener_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    void enqueue_md(netw::Packet* packet)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(pending_md_mtx_);
        pending_md_.push(packet);
    }

    void process_md()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(pending_md_mtx_);
        while (pending_md_.size())
        {
            netw::Packet* pkt=pending_md_.front();
            pending_md_.pop();
            process_md(*pkt);
        }
    }
    //... Other code which I can't post...

private:
    ListenerT listener_;
    std::mutex pending_md_mtx_;
    std::queue<netw::Packet*> pending_md_;
};
```

GDB Stacktrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2f20aa75e6f4000) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:50
#1  0x000000000041a2dc in __gthread_mutex_lock (__mutex=0xff282ceacb40) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/gthr-default.h:742
#2  lock (this=0xff282ceacb40) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/mutex:90
#3  lock_guard (__m=..., this=0x7f2874fc4db0) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/mutex:445
#4  driver::Driver<Listener, false>::enqueue_md (this=0xff282ceac8a0, packet=...) at exec/../../driver/Driver.hpp:95
```

Comment: You need to show a bit more about how `pending_md_mtx_` is declared and accessed.

Comment: The error is not in the code shown: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c532102f3e1d151aa3606419ef41ac77-f0f4984a193759175f04eadfe43758cb

Comment: Is it remotely possible the *instance* of `Driver<T>` that you're using is not valid? For example, `Driver<MyType> *p; p->enqueue_md(param);` will certainly *compile*, but equally certainly invoke undefined behavior since the instance is completely invalid.

Comment: Is it possible for `enqueue_md` to be called from `process_md(*pkt)`, hence attempting to lock the mutex that is already held by this thread?

Comment: Interesting question. Under what circumstances might it be invalid? Several other method calls go off without a hitch, and this crash seems to be non-deterministic. I did a clean build and still experience the crash... sometimes.

Comment: Most likely missing the `-pthread` option for GCC; multithreaded code is not guaranteed to work without it.

Comment: `process_md` does not call `enqueue_md`. Something I find odd is that the address of `__mutex` in frame 1 differs drastically from `mutex` in frame 0. That address looks strange, and I believe it is that access (0x2f20aa75e6f4000) which is causing the segfault.

Comment: Is -pthread required for compilation of object files, or just for the linking step?

Comment: For both compiling and linking. No need to specify `-lpthread`, `-pthread` takes care of that.

Comment: "I see," said the blind man... Doing a fresh build now.

Comment: Curious. I recompiled with -pthread and it crashed. Then I recompiled again with -O0 and it ran fine for several minutes...

Comment: Is that `Driver` object properly constructed by the time you start calling `enqueue_md`? Why isn't main() showing up in the stack trace? Is it being called from the constructor of a global object?

Comment: I didn't post the full stack trace. The general idea is that we have an asynchronous thread receiving data and queueing them for processing in the above object. A separate thread repeatedly calls `process_md()` in a loop to process. The above object is constructed before any calls to `enqueue_md` are made (it's ctor is empty).

Comment: This may be an issue of the `-pthread` flag + stale build files. I'll monitor it for a bit longer and then accept the `-pthread` solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a segfault on constructing the `std::lock_guard`, turns out my code was using an uninitialized `std::shared_ptr<my_object_with_mutex>`.  Using a properly constructed `my_object_with_mutex` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem. It was caused by line of code causing a buffer overrun after acquiring the lock. It would seem odd for a line of code below the lock to be causing a problem a few lines earlier, but I suppose the buffer overrun would cause some corruption that causes a problem on a second call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue rootcause in my case:

1. An object A references object B
2. On call to object `B.func()` I see a SegFault on lock_guard
3. Object B has never been set for object A (not initialized, a NULL pointer), leading to a SegFault on accessing a field (mutex, in my case).

The error could be diagnosed from GDB by noticing `this=0x0`:

```
...
#4  0x000055e3a9e14a3c in B<C>::write (this=0x4e2280, msg=0x55e3aac03be0) at /proj/B.hpp:35
#5  0x000055e3a9e206e6 in A::write (this=0x0, msg=0x55e3aac03be0) at /proj/A.cpp:286
#6  0x000055e3a9e2069a in A::write (this=0x7f21eae64010, msg=0x55e3aac03be0) at /proj/A.cpp:277
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the root cause was the same (object with mutex uninitialized), but the reason was not.

The object that had the mutex had a function `reset`. Guess what, `shared_ptr` has also a function named `reset`, and I called that instead!

Avoid using `reset` as a name, or double-check if you're not using `obj.reset()` instead of `obj->reset()`!